# Pi code stops running after several minutes with no error message

Tags: gpio

As stated above the PI stops running the code after several minutes and gives no error at all. The PI is perfectly fine and the code will work as soon as I stop it and restart it. This code needs to run for an extended period of time so this is not good. (Code listed below)

```
import os
import time 
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from w1thermsensor import W1ThermSensor
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(40, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(35, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(35, True)
tempsen = W1ThermSensor()
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
start_time = time.time()
time.sleep(1)
ref_time = time.time()
realtime = ref_time - start_time
elapsed_tme = round(realtime)
temp = (temsen.get_tempature()) * (9/5) + 32
while True:
    GPIO.output(35, True) 
    while temp < 89.5:
        GPIO.output(40, True)
        temp = (temsen.get_tempature()) * (9/5) + 32
        print(temp)
        time.sleep(1)
    while temp > 90.5 
        GPIO.output(40, False)
        temp = (temsen.get_tempature()) * (9/5) + 32
        print(temp)
        time.sleep(1)
        os.system('clear')
```

Comment: Move temp=... inside your 'while True:' loop. Add print(temp) and time.sleep(0.1) inside your 'while True' loop.

Comment: Currently your code will get stuck in a loop when temp >= 89.5 and <= 90.5

Comment: i.e. once temp is between 89.5 and 90.5, the value of temp is never read again, so therefore neither of those inner conditions will ever be true

Comment: This belongs in a coding forum rather than RPi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be useful if you defined "stops running". I was looking for something which caused the program to exit. In fact, the program is probably running perfectly well, doing what it's supposed to. Rather, it "stops generating output." This is because (assuming the temperature is slowly increasing) it stops looking for input once it hits 89.5.

Just before you enter your infinite while loop, you query the temperature once and only once. Then, when inside your while loop, you only query the temperature if it's <89.5 or >90.5. As such, if the temperature is between those points, it doesn't get queried.

Further, because the temperature doesn't get read between those points, once it enters that zone, the temperature will never ever be queried again.

Step through your program manually line-at-a-time and ask yourself "what happens here?"

Suggestion (untested):

```
import os
import time 
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from w1thermsensor import W1ThermSensor
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(40, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(35, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(35, True)
tempsen = W1ThermSensor()
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
start_time = time.time()
time.sleep(1)
ref_time = time.time()
realtime = ref_time - start_time
elapsed_tme = round(realtime)
while True:
    temp = (temsen.get_tempature()) * (9/5) + 32
    GPIO.output(35, True) 
    while temp < 89.5:
        GPIO.output(40, True)
        print(temp)
        time.sleep(1)
    while temp > 90.5 
        GPIO.output(40, False)
        print(temp)
        time.sleep(1)
        os.system('clear')
```

This version ALWAYS reads the temperature, but only outputs it when it's outside body temperature.

Notice that, if the temperature is too high it will print it then clear the screen, whereas if it's too low, it won't clear the screen. I don't know why you've done that.